# separate executables to store onto SSD

Tags: ssd

I want a solid-state-drive (SSD) for speed but since they degrade when written to, I want to keep frequently written/rewritten files on my old HD.

1. Is there a common arrangement already available to isolate boot and program files for read-only (like run from DVD) ?,
2. Will I  be thwarted by latest-access stamps updated even when their files are only read/executed ?

Answer (score 0):

there's a few tweaks that are recommended.

http://www.howtogeek.com/62761/how-to-tweak-your-ssd-in-ubuntu-for-better-performance/

I'm a bad use case, I don't usually use as many partitions as is recommended, but I would put my /tmp in ramfs most computers have more then enough memory for this.

and /home I would put on a regular drive.

your programs/configs don't change that often.  IMO I think your $HOME changes a lot more frequently, and /tmp is written frequently which is why I allocated some space in ram.

These aren't necessarily the best choices, just what I've done myself.